# Display currency text and box to left side

Tags: html, css

if you see top right [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/human-skulls-and-bones-apple-iphone-4s-phone-case.html) , we can see currency dropdown box.

[image]

i want to move that dropdown box to left side

```
 .a123

{
    position: absolute;
    right: -70px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 15px;
}   
.dropDownMenu a:first-child {
    color: #636363;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I tried with `position:relative;right:somepx;` but only text moved to left, i want to both text and box to be moved to left side.

Comment: thanks a lot @Mitul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
.a123 
{

   position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: it feels great to help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

try this `float:left` it will set your box on left. I hope it'll help you.